# Proof of the matrix form of the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, linear-groups, unitary-matrices

The Lie algebra elements fulfill

$$\mathfrak su(2) =\{X: \text {Tr} (X) = 0 \;, X^\dagger = - X \}.\tag 1$$

$$\mathfrak su(2) = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} ix & y + iz \\ -y+iz & -ix \end{bmatrix}\;x,y,z\in \mathbb R \right\},$$

On the other hand the Lie group is

$$SU(2)=\{A: \det(A)=1 \;, A^\dagger A=1 \}.$$

This implies matrices of the form

$$SU(2) = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ -\bar b & \bar a \end{bmatrix}\;a,b\in \mathbb C,\vert a \vert^2+ \vert b \vert^2=1 \right\},$$

since $A^\dagger A=1 \implies A^\dagger A^{-1},$ and the determinant is $1.$

I guess that to prove $(1)$ either the log or the exponential mapping would have to be used with some Taylor expansion at least to the linear term, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: If $A(t)$ is differentiable with $A'(0)=X$, then differentiating $A^{\dagger}A=I$ at $t=0$ yields $X^{\dagger}+X=0$.

Comment: @runway44 Thank you. Can you expand on the mechanics, and touch upon the zero trace?

Comment: What do you mean by mechanics? As for trace, if you differentiate $\det A=1$ at $t=0$ you get ${\rm tr}\,X=0$.

Comment: @runway44 It would be great if you considered an answer with the application of the product rule to $A^\dagger A=0,$ predictable as it may be. Same for the differentiation of $\det A=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have$$\mathfrak{su}(2)=\left\{X\in GL(2,\Bbb C)\,\middle|\,(\forall t\in\Bbb R):\exp(tX)\in SU(2)\right\}.$$But, if $X\in GL(2,\Bbb C)$ and $t\in\Bbb R$,\begin{align}\exp(tX)\in SU(2)&\iff\exp(tX)^\dagger\exp(tX)=\operatorname{Id}\text{ and }\det\bigl(\exp(tX)\bigr)=1\\&\iff\exp\left(tX^\dagger\right)=\exp(tX)^{-1}\text{ and }\exp\bigl(\operatorname{tr}(tX)\bigr)=1\\&\iff\exp\left(tX^\dagger\right)=\exp(-tX)\text{ and }\exp\bigl( t(\operatorname{tr}(X)\bigr)=1\end{align}and, since these equalities occur for each $t\in\Bbb R$,$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\exp\left(tX^\dagger\right)\right|_{t=0}=\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\exp(-tX)\right|_{t=0}\quad\text{and}\quad\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\exp\bigl( t(\operatorname{tr}(X)\bigr)\right|_{t=0}=0,$$which is the same thing as asserting that $X^\dagger=-X$ and that $\operatorname{tr}(X)=0$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm missing technical fundamentals here... It seems as though, having established that the matrices are over the field of complex numbers, the transpose notation in your answer is identical to the dagger? Also, can you show how the trace has to be zero?

Comment: It's me that should have used the dagger instead of working with the transpose. And I've added the proof that $\operatorname{tr}(X)=0$.